# Except two digits,make all the digits of integer to zero-Java

Tags: java, regex, converters, digit

I have some integer values like **1447948,21163176,95999** and I wanna make them like that:

- 1447948--> **1400000**
- 21163176-->**21000000**
- 95999-->**95000**

How can I make this with using java?

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the logic of how many significant digits you want to keep? E.g., why if `95999` turned in to `95000` and not `95900`?

Comment: Beyond that, the answer is basically adapting what you can get from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407634/rounding-up-to-the-nearest-hundred .... well, when you got clear on your requirements that is. You have to understand what exactly you intend to do!

Comment: @Leviand Nonsense. He wants to round whole numbers to the next hundred/thousand/hundred thousand(?). floor() is for rounding float numbers ...

Comment: Yes,there is a difference from what I am looking for.I want to round the numbers to the next hundred,thousand numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because rounding is something that is count from the right, you cannot use it, you can just pass from string and use a basic regex to replace the non-2 first digits by `0` :

```
int val = 1447948;
int res = Integer.valueOf((""+val).replaceAll("(?<=\\d{2})\\d", "0"));
//  res : 1400000
```

`(?<=\\d{2})\\d` match the digits that have two digits before them

[***`Workable Demo`***](https://ideone.com/iArumL)

Comment: Or `.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{2})\\d", "0")` ([Demo](https://ideone.com/CVqGPe)).

Comment: @Pshemo ow thanks, not a regex expert, and surely not on lookbehind/ahead, yours is easier to understand. But, is my definition of the one I give correct ?

Comment: I don't see problem with your previous solution except that it was *little* more complex that what I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Math is your friend.

```
int magnitude = (int) Math.pow(10, Math.log10(n) - 1)
int o = (int) Math.floor(n / magnitude) * magnitude
```

where `n` is the input number and `o` is the output number.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for any number by treating it as a string:

```
int number = 1447948;
String number1 = String.valueOf(number);
String[] split = number1.split("");
StringBuilder number2 = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  if(i > 1)
    number2.append("0");
  else
    number2.append(split[i]);
}
int result = Integer.parseInt(number2.toString());
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend.That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I fixed some minor things in your code. For example you simply call toString() on a StringBuilder in the end.

Comment: Thank You @GhostCat