# Round off to nearest hundred in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, double

I came to a part in my flutter app where I need to round up to the nearest hundred and thought that there was probably some way to do it but I guess not. So I searched the net for examples or any answers and I've yet to find any since all examples appear to be to the nearest hundred. I just want to do this and round UP. Maybe there's some simple solution that I'm overlooking. I have tried double.roundToDouble() but it does not work for me. If anyone could help me with this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

If my number is 199.03, I want the result rounded to 200.00.

```
199.08->200.00
99.30->100.00
14.99->15.00
499.09->500.00
```

**What I tried**

```
.roundToDouble (this does not work as 199.08.roundToDouble returns as 199.0)
```

Comment: Maybe playing around with the math used here will do what you want : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407634/rounding-up-to-the-nearest-hundred

Comment: Rounding 14.99 to the nearest hundred would be 0, not 15...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example I wrote. You can try it by pasting it [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
  List<double> examples = [
    199.08,
    99.3,
    14.99,
    499.09,
  ];

  for (int i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
    double num = examples[i];

    double roundedNumber = num.ceilToDouble();

    print("$num -> $roundedNumber");
  }
```

You can use `ceil` method to achieve this.

**RESULT**:

```
199.08 -> 200
99.3 -> 100
14.99 -> 15
499.09 -> 500
```

Answer (score 1):

```
double val = 199.03;
int roundedToNearestHundred = ((val + 50) ~/ 100) * 100).toInt();
```

```
void main() {
  List<double> v = [
    199.03,
    1250.00,
    1249.99,
    1250.01, 
    49.99,
    50.00,
    50.01,
  ];
  v.forEach((val) => print((((val + 50) ~/ 100) * 100).toInt()));
}
```

This will give in result:

```
200
1300
1200
1300
0
100
100
```