# How to sequentially generate identifier for object in java?

Tags: java

> The identifier consists of predefined prefix, specific for ticket type, and a number. The number for every newly created Object is incremented in a sequential order.
>
> Field                Mask                        Example
>   Name               [name of object] #XXXXXX   Sample #123456
>   Number             SC-XXXXXX                      SC-123456
>
> How to append first 5 places with 0's like 000001

Comment: possible ducplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416826/sequence-generator-in-java-for-unique-id

Comment: The real answer is to let the database do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). It's as simple as this:

```
AtomicInteger sequentialNumber = new AtomicInteger();
int nextNumber = sequentialNumber.incrementAndGet();
```

[EDIT]

To prepend with zeros use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html). In your case `String.format("%06d", number);` where *0* is the pad character and *6* is the total width.

Comment: How to append first 5 places with 0's like 000001

Comment: I've updated the answer...